# Error Message: "Makefile:1: *** Malformed target-specific variable definition. Stop."

Tags: makefile, gnu

I am a student, and for my homework i was asked to create a few simple programs, a makefile, and a run script. No matter what I try, I keep receiving the same error message when typing "make" as a command in the server where I am to work on and submit this homework. I have spent many hours trying to resolve this on my own, and I believe that this error is outside the scope of my education thus far.

I have attached the makefile.

```
all: define calcdrawing encrypt
define: define.cpp
    g++ define.cpp -o define
calcdrawing: calcdrawing.cpp
    g++ calcdrawing.cpp -o calcdrawing
encrypt: encrypt.cpp
    g++ encrypt.cpp -o encrypt
```

I receive the following error message:

```
Makefile:1: *** Malformed target-specific variable definition. Stop.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot use the keyword `define` as you intended

replace your code make file with

```
    all: mydefine calcdrawing encrypt
    mydefine: define.cpp
        g++ define.cpp -o define
    calcdrawing: calcdrawing.cpp
        g++ calcdrawing.cpp -o calcdrawing
    encrypt: encrypt.cpp
        g++ encrypt.cpp -o encrypt
```

change my define to any name